# how to use ggrepel when facetting?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanna avoid the overlapping of labes for columns.

Adding:

`geom_label_repel(aes(label = amount_spent), size = 2)`

To my GGplot code,returns:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  Viewport has zero dimension(s)
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

How to make it work?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(excel.link)
library(ggrepel)
library(hrbrthemes)


ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = amount_spent, fill = segmentacion)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(group = segmentacion,
                label = scales::dollar(amount_spent)),
               vjust = -0.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  labs(x="xx22", y="Invesment",
       title="x",
       subtitle="",
       caption="xxx") + 
  theme_ipsum(grid="Y") +
  facet_grid(. ~ div) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = amount_spent), size = 2)
```

sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19289, 19289, 19289, 19289, 
19289, 19289, 19289, 19290, 19290, 19290, 19290, 19290, 19290, 
19290, 19291, 19291, 19291, 19291, 19291, 19291, 19291, 19292, 
19292, 19292, 19292, 19292, 19292, 19292, 19293, 19293, 19293, 
19293, 19293, 19293, 19293), class = "Date"), div = c("da", "da", 
"mx", "mx", "mx", "vd", "vd", "da", "da", "mx", "mx", "mx", "vd", 
"vd", "da", "da", "mx", "mx", "mx", "vd", "vd", "da", "da", "mx", 
"mx", "mx", "vd", "vd", "da", "da", "mx", "mx", "mx", "vd", "vd"
), segmentacion = c("primaria", "rmkt", "lal", "primaria", "rmkt", 
"primaria", "rmkt", "primaria", "rmkt", "lal", "primaria", "rmkt", 
"primaria", "rmkt", "primaria", "rmkt", "lal", "primaria", "rmkt", 
"primaria", "rmkt", "primaria", "rmkt", "lal", "primaria", "rmkt", 
"primaria", "rmkt", "primaria", "rmkt", "lal", "primaria", "rmkt", 
"primaria", "rmkt"), amount_spent = c(27.15, 66.28, 1702.57, 
1425.61, 1807.61, 2834.54, 4575.69, 24.27, 61.07, 1944.62, 1830.42, 
2250.64, 2765.84, 4185.05, 27.06, 61.23, 1851.48, 1173.36, 1324.46, 
2732.69, 4079.26, 24.37, 45.7, 2727.94, 1169.27, 1712.19, 2919.12, 
3442.32, 39.3, 40.57, 4646.62, 1724.75, 2175.31, 3479.91, 2243.2
), impressions = c(43634, 24630, 921583, 1216668, 743986, 1487846, 
1696389, 21527, 18805, 1060447, 1374010, 981014, 1455044, 1645824, 
27046, 19592, 917694, 1034479, 493042, 1254737, 1594285, 8929, 
15367, 1351139, 942873, 617220, 1240450, 1245851, 12894, 13189, 
1896225, 1251892, 753184, 1386182, 634107), outbound_clicks = c(356, 
423, 5619, 8727, 7788, 5726, 6190, 255, 340, 5567, 10936, 5898, 
5301, 5285, 363, 350, 4969, 8023, 3823, 5397, 5733, 142, 209, 
5388, 6735, 4264, 5466, 4800, 172, 177, 8486, 7527, 4788, 6456, 
3501), visits = c(201, 265, 6935, 503, 15466, 1708, 1991, 168, 
225, 5151, 2112, 11160, 1606, 1654, 296, 227, 4681, 724, 8474, 
1900, 1825, 80, 158, 4930, 886, 7222, 2010, 1678, 104, 120, 4291, 
1358, 7524, 2154, 1252), orders = c(0, 1, 65, 2, 53, 11, 10, 
0, 0, 51, 4, 56, 7, 8, 2, 0, 55, 1, 39, 12, 12, 1, 1, 20, 2, 
55, 17, 14, 1, 1, 47, 0, 37, 27, 13), revenue_dolars_sin_igv = c(0, 
301.889473684211, 20809.0105263158, 1876.93684210527, 26216.9256315789, 
4569.98947368421, 4680.47584210526, 0, 0, 12043.6421052631, 1962.82105263158, 
22091.2358947368, 3192.17368421053, 3709.85263157894, 744.042105263158, 
0, 22932.5947368421, 1402.41578947368, 13447.3569473684, 5154.77894736842, 
6600.35263157896, 301.889473684211, 301.889473684211, 5111.61889473684, 
1084.77368421053, 14732.1631578947, 7376.33157894737, 7225.71052631579, 
301.889473684211, 301.889473684211, 19366.0241578947, 0, 16299.8736842105, 
14172.4484210526, 5348.77368421053)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -35L), groups = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(19289, 19289, 19289, 19290, 19290, 19290, 
    19291, 19291, 19291, 19292, 19292, 19292, 19293, 19293, 19293
    ), class = "Date"), div = c("da", "mx", "vd", "da", "mx", 
    "vd", "da", "mx", "vd", "da", "mx", "vd", "da", "mx", "vd"
    ), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:5, 6:7, 8:9, 10:12, 13:14, 
        15:16, 17:19, 20:21, 22:23, 24:26, 27:28, 29:30, 31:33, 
        34:35), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .drop = TRUE))
```

sessionsInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Peru.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Peru.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Peru.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Spanish_Peru.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggrepel_0.9.1     openxlsx_4.2.5    excel.link_0.9.10 anytime_0.3.9     patchwork_1.1.2  
 [6] scales_1.2.0      hrbrthemes_0.8.0  janitor_2.1.0     forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0    
[11] dplyr_1.0.9       purrr_0.3.4       readr_2.1.2       tidyr_1.2.0       tibble_3.1.7     
[16] ggplot2_3.3.6     tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        lubridate_1.8.0   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.29     utf8_1.2.2       
 [6] R6_2.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.4.1   reprex_2.0.1      evaluate_0.15    
[11] httr_1.4.3        pillar_1.7.0      gdtools_0.2.4     rlang_1.0.4       readxl_1.4.0     
[16] rstudioapi_0.13   extrafontdb_1.0   rmarkdown_2.14    labeling_0.4.2    extrafont_0.18   
[21] munsell_0.5.0     broom_1.0.0       compiler_4.1.2    modelr_0.1.8      xfun_0.31        
[26] pkgconfig_2.0.3   systemfonts_1.0.4 htmltools_0.5.2   tidyselect_1.1.2  fansi_1.0.3      
[31] crayon_1.5.1      tzdb_0.3.0        dbplyr_2.2.1      withr_2.5.0       grid_4.1.2       
[36] jsonlite_1.8.0    Rttf2pt1_1.3.11   gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.1   DBI_1.1.3        
[41] magrittr_2.0.3    zip_2.2.0         cli_3.3.0         stringi_1.7.6     farver_2.1.1     
[46] fs_1.5.2          snakecase_0.11.0  xml2_1.3.3        ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.3   
[51] vctrs_0.4.1       tools_4.1.2       glue_1.6.2        hms_1.1.1         fastmap_1.1.0    
[56] colorspace_2.0-3  rvest_1.0.2       knitr_1.39        haven_2.5.0
```

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce, using the provided data and the code I'm not seeing any error. Try restart your R session

Comment: It's also working fine for me. How are you viewing this? I think sometimes ggrepel doesn't show up depending on how your view it.

Comment: Works for me as well!